# How to get a good Force Feedback .dll Feedback for Steering Wheels? || How to access Force Feedback without a .dll?

Tags: unity, dll, force-feedback

I want to implement a steering wheel with Force Feedback to my game and I encountered this problem:
I couldnt do it with performance.
I have found a .dll for that online, but it had issues like:

1. It was not performant
2. It made my steering wheel react too delayed

Otherwise I was not able to access the steering wheel.
Is it even possible to make a performant steering wheel and force feedback game  with good performance?
How else can I access force feedback ?

Comment: I see this question has been flagged as too broad. Some ways you might be able to narrow it down would be to describe what specific hardware models you want to support (I'm not sure if, or to what degree, there's a common standard for interfacing with all such devices in a uniform fashion), or include the code you've been using to interact with the wheel so far.

Comment: It may help me and a lot of others if some expert could fill out the tag wiki for `force-feedback`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which dll you already tried, so these may be duplicates, but:

There's a Unity asset which can apparently help with this (e.g. https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/ginputcontrollers-multi-joystick-and-force-feedback-manager-94949).

Here's another (currently in development, but forum posts suggest the beta releases work fine with steering wheels): https://vehiclephysics.com/about/demos/

Worst case scenario, you could write your own dll using DirectX's `DirectInput` or `XInput` APIs, which *should* be able to do this.